# What type of product should I use to seal siding to a concrete step?

Tags: concrete, seal

I would like to seal the outside of my home from the elements and rain, where the concrete meets the side of my home (painted wood?)

Home Side
[image: Home Side]

Wide Angle
[image: Home Wide]

I bought a tube of [Dap Dynaflex Ultra](https://www.dap.com/products-projects/product-categories/caulks-sealants/latex/dynaflex-ultra/), which reads that it stays flexible, all weather protection, UV, and 100% waterproof.

Is the Dynaflex ultra a good product to use or is there a product more suited for the job?

Comment: It depends. Does water pool up? Will it pool up more? Maybe the gap, although narrow,  is for drainage

Comment: IMHO, the "right product" is a jackhammer to remove concrete that was poured in an inappropriate location, or else a house-jacking company to jack the wood parts of the house up so you can extend the concrete foundation wall (assumed) upwards beyond this concrete slab. Whatever you do other than those, this will rot out your walls. If your area has termites, they'll do additional damage.

Answer (score 2):

The caulk you purchased can certainly be used for the sealing you need.

I would use a polyurethane caulk like [Vulkem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8410400243).

The 2 caulks are both suitable. They both have pros and cons.

The differences are the dynaflex allows water
clean up and the surfaces have to be very clean for it to adhere.

The vulkem needs mineral spirits for clean up, but sticks to everything! Just remove any loose material and apply.